# What is the equivalent pattern in haskell for replacing conditionals with polymorphism?

Tags: c++, haskell

I've been exploring Haskell to get some functional programming experience. I'm hoping to find patterns that bring some insight so I can write better c++. For instance, I find the normal implementation of converting a switch statement to polymorphic code unsatisfying.

```cpp
void HandleMessage(int type, Message m)
{
   switch (type)
   {
   case 1:
      HandleType1(m);
      break;
   case 2:
      HandleType2(m);
      break;
   default:
      Log("error, unhandled message type")
   }
}
```

becomes:

```cpp
void HandleMessage(Type t, Message m)
{
   std::unique_ptr<HandlerInterface> handler = HandlerFactory.GetHandler(t);
   handler.handleMessage(m);
}

std::unique_ptr<HandlerInterface> HandlerFactory::GetHandler(Type t)
{
   switch (t)
   {
   case 1:
      return std::make_unique<HandlerType1>();
   case 2:
      return std::make_unique<HandlerType2>();
   default:
      return std::make_unique<DefaultHandler>();
   }
}
```

This just pushes the switch to the factory. It's probably better than the first solution, but it just feels like there should be something better.

I was wondering if a better pattern exists in Haskell. I know you can use guards:

```hs
handleMessage t msg
   | t == 1 = handleType1 msg
   | t == 2 = handleType2 msg
```

But this doesn't seem that much more elegant. You could switch the types as ints to a proper type and do pattern matching:

```hs
data Type = Type1 | Type2

createType t
   | t == 1 = Type1
   | t == 2 = Type2

handleMessage Type1 msg = handleType1 msg
handleMessage Type2 msg = handleType2 msg
```

Again, we can push the switch around, but I'm not really seeing something elegant. I'm hoping for several things:

1. Cohesion: code is bundled together well.
2. Adding a new handle requires little boilerplate. None would be preferred!
3. Nice to have: Missing a handler for a particular type would be a compilation error.

Comment: Err... that's not how you eliminate a `switch`, even in C++. You'd make two subclasses of `Message`, one with its `handle` method doing what `HandleType1` does, and one with its `handle` method doing what `HandleType2` does. Then you'd dispense with the "type" stuff entirely and just write `m.handle()`. A similar thing can be done in Haskell, if you care, with typeclasses.

Comment: Your example doesn't yet provide a compelling argument for combining two functions `handleType1` and `handleType2` under one function. Who calls `createType`, and why wouldn't they just use `handleType1` and `handleType2` directly, instead of introducing the artificial tag type `Type`?

Comment: @DanielWagner how do you create your polymorphic message? How do you send one over a wire?

Comment: @DanielWagner I followed the advice about using typeclasses, thanks so much

Comment: @n.m. I don't get the question, what do you mean "over a wire"? sorry I didn't understand quite well that part

Comment: @DamianLattenero send it over the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Your Haskell solutulion is a near copy of the first C++ fragment. It only looks better because of Haskell's terser syntax, but it does exactly the same thing. Actually an exact C++ equivalent would be

```
enum Type { Type1, Type2 };
...
Type getType(int type) {
  switch (type) {
      case 1: return Type1;
      case 2: return Type2;
    ...
 ...
 switch (getType(type)) {
     case Type1: // etc etc
```

As you can see there isn't too much of wonderful and exciting functional programming going on. Indeed, functional programming is about programming with *functions as first class values*. There ain't any in your example.

Let's change it a bit.

```
....
handler Type1 = handleType1
handler Type2 = handleType2
```

So now `handler` is a primitive higher-order function. It gets a Type and returns another function. This still isn't much, but this translates to C++ this way:

```
void handleType1(Message);
void handleType2(Message);

auto getHandler(Type type) {
  switch(type) {
      case Type1: return handleType1;
      case Type2: return handleType2;
    ....
```

So instead of returning an object, you return a function. This is not a coimcidence. *An object is just a bunch of functions* (its methods). An object with one method is just a function!

Wait, what about data? Isn't an object made up of methods *and data*? It is, but its data can be bound in a function (think lambda or std::bind). Normal C++ functions (function pointers) cannot capture context, but you just use lambdas and std::function.

So I guess this example doesn't bring too much insight to the table in the end. Instead of objects,use functions, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can do pattern matching on Int:

```
createType 1 = Type1
createType 2 = Type2
createType _ = error("error, unhandled message type")

handleMessage n msg = handleType (createType n) msg

handleType Type1 msg = doSome...
handleType Type2 msg = doSome2...
```

But if you don't want to do that, you can directly do pattern matching on Types:

```
handleType Type1 msg = handle1 msg
handleType Type2 msg = handle2 msg
```

But even better would be using a type class:

```
class Handler a where
  handleMsg :: a -> String -> IO ()


data Type = Type1 | Type2

instance Handler Type where
  handleMsg Type1 = handle1
  handleMsg Type2 = handle2

handle1 msg = putStrLn $ "handle1 " ++ msg
handle2 msg = putStrLn $ "handle2 " ++ msg 

main = do
  handleMsg Type1 "error 1"
  handleMsg Type2 "error 2"
```

Comment: What exact benefit does a type class provide here? Why isn't `handleMsg` a function of type `Type -> String -> IO ()` ?